# Does this moment inequality hold for any probability measure on the positive real line?

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, moments

#### Problem statement

Let $P$ be a probability measure on the positive real line and assume all it's *raw moments*, $\mu_k = \mathbb{E}[x^k]$, $k=1,2,\dots$ exist and $\mu_k < \infty$ for all $k$.  Let $\mu = \mu_1$ be the mean of $P$ and assume $\mu > 0$.

Does the following inequality hold?
$$
4 \frac{\mu_3}{\mu^3} + 6 \frac{\mu_2}{\mu^2} - 9\left(\frac{\mu_2}{\mu^2}\right)^2 - 1 \leq 0
$$

#### Further remarks

I have tried to find a counterexample experimentally and found the above holds over a wide variety of continuous distributions (i.e. Gamma and Beta distributions) and may be tight in the sense that there are distributions which are just below zero.

#### Pointers

From [*Stieltjes moment problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_moment_problem) we know that for any measure on the positive real line we must have that

$$
\det\left(\left[\begin{array}{cc}
  1 & \mu\\
  \mu & \mu_2
\end{array}
\right]\right) > 0,
\qquad\textrm{and}\qquad
\det\left(\left[\begin{array}{cc}
  \mu & \mu_2\\
  \mu_2 & \mu_3
\end{array}\right]\right) > 0,
$$
from which we can infer that
$$
\frac{\mu_2}{\mu^2} > 1,
\qquad\textrm{and}\qquad
\frac{\mu_3}{\mu^3} > \left(\frac{\mu_2}{\mu^2}\right)^2.
$$

(But I have not been able to show the above inequality based on this.)

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't hold.
Note that if one chooses $P= \frac{1}{n^2} \delta_n + \frac{n^2-1}{n^2} \delta_x$ with $x$ chosen such that $\mu = 1$, i.e. $x = \frac{n^2-n}{n^2-1}$, then $\mu_3 \sim n$ asymptotically, while all other terms are bounded.

Or for a concrete counter example, take $n = 10$, then $\mu_2 = 1.8182$, $\mu_3 = 10.7438$ and the left hand side evaluates to $23.1322$.